# PyQt widget reload or refresh

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt, reload

My problem is that when I choose a name on widget "Form1" this name is written to file. When I click on OK button on widget "Form1" I can't see the same name on widget "Form2" which I chose previously.

The problem is that the widget "Form2" is not up to date. I tried to insert self.update at the beginning on the widget "Form2" but it doesn't work. How can I refresh widget "Form2" or reload the content of the file?

I have a simple code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

from functools import partial
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from math import sqrt
from time import gmtime, strftime

class Form1(QWidget):
    showForm2Signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form1, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(0, 40, 480, 400)
        self.label.move(0,40)

        #Select name
        self.styleTerminalSettings = QtGui.QLabel("Please select your name:", self)
        self.styleTerminalSettings.move(20,40)
        self.styleTerminalSettings.resize(250,30)
        self.styleTerminalSettings.setStyleSheet("color: black;  background-color: transparent; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;")

        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.addItem("NAME 1")
        self.comboBox.addItem("NAME 2")
        self.comboBox.addItem("NAME 3")
        self.comboBox.addItem("NAME 4")
        self.comboBox.move(20,80)
        self.comboBox.resize(440,50)
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selectionchange)

        #OK button
        self.ok_button = QtGui.QPushButton("OK", self)
        self.ok_button.resize(self.ok_button.minimumSizeHint())
        self.ok_button.move(0,340)
        self.ok_button.resize(480,60)
        self.ok_button.setStyleSheet("color: #25373D; background-color: #71BA51;  font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold;")

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.ok_button.clicked.connect(self.showForm2Signal.emit)

    def selectionchange(self,i): 
        pos_user_name = self.comboBox.currentText()
        self.users_write(pos_user_name)

    #Name write to file 
    def users_write(self, pos_user_name):
        filename = "user_name_session"

        target = open(filename, 'w')
        target.truncate()
        target.write(pos_user_name)
        target.close()    

class Form2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form2, self).__init__(parent)

        global pos_user_name 

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(0, 40, 480, 400)
        self.label.move(0,40)

        #Name read from file
        filename = "user_name_session"
        target = open(filename, "r+")
        name = target.read(10);

        self.styleCashRegister = QtGui.QLabel("Name:", self)
        self.styleCashRegister.move(20,40)
        self.styleCashRegister.resize(170,30)
        self.styleCashRegister.setStyleSheet("color: black; background-color: transparent;  font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold;")

        self.cashregisterid = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.cashregisterid.setText(str(name))
        self.cashregisterid.move(100, 40)
        self.cashregisterid.resize(260,30)
        self.cashregisterid.setStyleSheet("color: #25373D;  font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold;")

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.stack = QStackedWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.stack)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 480, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("PYQT WIDGET TEST")
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #E8E8E8")

        self.form1 = Form1(self)
        self.form2 = Form2(self)

        self.stack.addWidget(self.form1)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.form2)

        self.form1.showForm2Signal.connect(partial(self.stack.setCurrentWidget,self.form2))

        self.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.form1) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could do this.  The first thing you need is a "refresh" function on form2 that will update the text on form2.

```
def refresh(self):
    filename = "user_name_session"
    target = open(filename, "r+")
    name = target.read(10);
    self.cashregisterid.setText(str(name))
```

The second thing you need is a way to call that `refresh` function whenever the file is rewritten.

You could just use the existing signal that form1 already emits to show form2.  In your MainWidget, connect that signal to the refresh function

```
self.form1.showForm2Signal.connect(self.form2.refresh)
```

Comment: Brendad Abel: I tried your tip but it doesn't work. Maybe this signal is bad? Please write over my code.

Comment: What didn't work?  Did you get an error?  Is the `refresh` function not being called?

Comment: I don't get error. I tested refresh function...I inserted print("ok") and I can see this on terminal. But I can't see widget "Form2", only "Form1" continuously.

Comment: Weren't you seeing form2 before, it just wasn't updating?  Did you remove the other signal connection?  You should have 2 signal connections -- one to switch the stack widget, and one to call the refresh function.